# How do you control multiple applications simultaneously?

Tags: windows

(ex) I have 2 games open on 2 of my monitors, I want to be able to control each game at the same time so if I move forward then both will move forward, If I look to the left then both will look to the left, but since windows will only let you control 1 program at a time then this is very hard to accomplish... By the way, I have multiple computers so controlling multiple computers is an option, but most software that I found that says you can control multiple computers only have like a cursor that lets you SWITCH between them which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJ428TJs6Mw

Comment: You could *try* using one wireless keyboard/mouse with two identical USB RF adapters... it might, or might not, work.